# Changing files names of more than 100 files

Tags: bash, files

So there's a folder in my directory which contains around 400-500 files (java, cpp, xml & etc) each with one name common for e.g

```
xml_1_ubuntu.xml
java_1_ubuntu.java
cpp_1_ubuntu.cpp
...
```

I wanna change the `ubuntu` in their name (irrespective of their extension/file type) to `notubuntu` so the work dir will have files like

```
xml_1_notubuntu.xml
java_1_notubuntu.java
cpp_1_notubuntu.cpp
...
```

is there anyway I can do this?

Answer (score 4):

Yes with the rename command using a normal regex:

```
rename -n 's/_ubuntu/_notubuntu/' *
```

`-n` makes it a dry-run. Remove it if this does what you want.

Comment: You might want to add the underscore in front of ubuntu, to avoid a possible rerun and notnotubuntu results.

Answer (score 2):

I would use `rename`.

```
rename -n 's@_(ubuntu\.)@_not$1@' *_ubuntu.*
```

You can do this in plain `bash` as well:

```
for f in *_ubuntu.* ; do
  base="${f%%_ubuntu.*}"
  ext="${f##*_ubuntu.}"
  mv "$f" "${base}_notubuntu.${ext}"
done
```

Answer (score 1):

With `mmv` (from package `mmv` in the Universe repository)

```
mmv -n -- '*_ubuntu*' '#1_notubuntu#2'
```

If you have access to the `zsh` shell you can use its `zmv` with a very similar syntax

```
autoload zmv
zmv -n -- '(*)_ubuntu(*)' '$1_notubuntu$2'
```

or more succinctly

```
zmv -n -- '(*)_(ubuntu*)' '$1_not$2'
```

In all cases, remove the `-n` once you are happy with the transformations.

Answer (score 0):

you can install GPRename, https://www.ghacks.net/2010/08/20/batch-rename-in-linux-with-gprename/ is  batch renamer for both files and directories that is released under the GPL v3. It's easy to install, and even easier to use.

open terminal  with CRTL+ALT+T:

```
sudo apt install gprename
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Without the `rename` command:

```
ls -1 | awk '{ name=$0; gsub(/ubuntu/,"notubuntu",name); print "mv " $0 " " name }' | bash
```

Without `| bash` at the end it will only display the commands without actually performing them (dry-run).

Comment: Oh no, you are [parsing Ls](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)!